# C++ размер char-массивов

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, производительность, char

[image: код]

Привет! Почему размеры разные? И можно ли в такой способ экономить память, использовавши const* char?

Comment: Потому что в первом случае вы измеряете не размер строки, а только указывающего на нее указателя, а во втором - размер всего массива... А в ответ на ваш вопрос - много вы наэкономите места в комнате, если вместо дивана будете спать на бумажке с надписью "диван возле окна"? :)

Comment: очень интересный ответ! спасибо

Comment: Harry, я бы добавил, что не просто спать на бумажке, но при том что в комнате еще и сам диван находится

Comment: Zhihar, значит использовать const char* сожрет больше места?

Comment: @Zhihar На бумажке же написано не просто "Диван", а "Диван у окна" - т.е. явное указание на то, что он в комнате...

Comment: а... ну тогда ок :)

Comment: а почему именно возле окна?

Comment: @ТарасПрограммер,  да нет, памяти столько же будет кушаться,  забавно посмотреть размеры вот таких конструкций `class A(){}; sizeof(A)` :)

Comment: @Zhihar а что в них забавного?

Comment: Croessmah, то почему она равна строго 1 байт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

возьмем пример проще, если вы не против:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данное "явление" связано с тем, что const char* это в каком-то смысле строка и имеет фиксированный размер, поэтому на первой строчке написано 4, как и всего элементов в нашей строке "аааа".
Во второй строчке написано 4 потому что это массив.

Оптимизации подлежит, да. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019

Comment: const* char имеет фиксированный размер. Как это понять?

Comment: а еще вопрос : почему возвращаемое значение функции main int32_t?

Comment: Имеет фиксированный размер значит, что если он имеет в себе 4 символа, то обратиться в 5-ому, например, не получится.


int32_t main() Осталось с прошлого проекта. Это связано с UTF-32 типом. Вы можете почитать про это в MSDN -> https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=msvc-160 

P.S. Там несколько статей про это. Листайте ниже, как только прочитаете.

Comment: Если написать `const char* a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";`, то всё равно выведет 4.

Comment: Размер указателя